# What am I doing wrong with this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm currently learning python and I'm trying to create an if statement for this but I can only get it to work for month or date not month and date.

```
date = int(input("Enter Date Here: "))

monthConversion = {
    "Jan": "January",
    "Feb": "February",
    "Mar": "March",
    "Apr": "April",
    "May": "May",
    "Jun": "June",
    "Jul": "July",
    "Aug": "August",
    "Sep": "September",
    "Oct": "October",
    "Nov": "November",
    "Dec": "December",
}

month = monthConversion.get(input("Enter Key Here: "), "Not a valid key")

if date == "26" and month == "January":
    print("That's My Birthday!!")

print(month, date)
```

Comment: you cast date to an `int` and then compare it to a `str` (`"26"`)

Comment: The title of the duplicate is a different question than yours, but the answers are all exactly what you need for solving this. It would probably not be hard to find a different duplicate because this is a very common beginner mistake, but I trust you got your problem solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the datatypes:
The variable date is an integer but in your if statement you compare it to a string "26". You either need to convert date to string or compare it to an integer.

```
if str(date) == "26" and month == "January":
    print("That's My Birthday!!")
```

or

```
if date == 26 and month == "January":
    print("That's My Birthday!!")
```

Comment: casting the input to an int and then back to a string seems unncessary. Why not either not cast it to an int in the first place or compare it to an int?

Comment: OP did not ask how to write this efficiently. The question is what's wrong with the IF statement. Since we know little about why he compares it to a string it is best to provide him with both options and let him choose based on his context.

Comment: While true, providing alternate solutions along with an explanation about why they might be better suited surely doesn't hurt. I like the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is fine except your `if` statement.
You are taking `date` input as an `int` but inside the `if` statement you have parenthesis which is for `str` not `int`.
Here, debugged version of your code:

```
date = int(input("Enter Date Here: "))

monthConversion = { "Jan": "January", "Feb": "February", "Mar": "March", "Apr": "April", "May": "May", "Jun": "June", "Jul": "July", "Aug": "August", "Sep": "September", "Oct": "October", "Nov": "November", "Dec": "December"}

month = monthConversion.get(input("Enter Key Here: "), "Not a valid key")

if date == 26 and month == "January":  # changes here
   print("That's My Birthday!!")

print(month, date)
```

Comment: Actually, the secnd prompt is quite hard to understand; it should probably say something like `"Enter month abbreviation: "`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to a int, you can try:

```py
if date == 26 and month == "January":
    print("That's My Birthday!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You casted date as int() but put it in quotes in the if statement. Just remove the quotes around `date == 26`in your code. It works.